# How to create a Sandbox Environment in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, sandbox

I am trying to create a Sandbox playground in AWS for Users to practice some resources for 30min, after that, all resources should be killed and account temporary account also should be deleted.

I got some information like Cloud Formation, Lambda and IAM combined can be used, Or AWS Control Tower also but I have no idea where to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need:

- A **separate AWS Account** so that anything created/deleted in the Account will not impact your normal environment (this account can be reused, there is no reason to use a new AWS Account each time you want a Sandbox)
- A **means of deleting resources** from the account when the time period is reached

Some example tools that can do this are:

- [AWS Nuke](https://github.com/rebuy-de/aws-nuke)
- [Cloud Nuke](https://github.com/gruntwork-io/cloud-nuke)

You would also need to write some code that ties everything together:

- Vending the account
- Tracking usage (eg when to clean)
- Triggering the cleanup script when time limit has been reached

**Bottom line:** It will take some work to create such a Sandbox.

Comment: What code i need to write and in which language, is it something in Lambda, Do you have any sample?